# Can I push to a gitlab repo using github handle?

Tags: github, gitlab

Pretty simple, really. I want to provide my github handle to gain access to a gitlab repo. Is this possible, or do I need to create an account on gitlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need a GitLab account.

One scenario where you can use GitLab with a GitHub account is "[Using GitLab CI/CD with a GitHub repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/github_integration.html)" (with Premium GitLab only).

There you could register in GitLab CI/CD settings a GitHub token.

But for pushing to a GitLab repository... you need GitLab credentials.